# What do folks think about adding (time-) dispersion and time-domain tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tagging

For [Do ASKAP and ALMA have "fast dump" interferometric modes? Can they see and perhaps report Fast Radio Bursts in real time?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/40664/7982) I've created two new tags: [tag:] and [tag:].

Before I start adding these to a few more questions how do folks feel about each of them?

#### Time Domain Astronomy

[Time Domain Astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_domain_astronomy) is a real thing, I think it's okay to add this tag and then to start adding it to future questions. Perhaps we should decide on a longest qualifying timescale for the tag though; seconds? minutes? months?

Months might be argued for supernovae and for the staggered appearances of lensed "echoes", but that might be too long. Periodic motion might be excluded as it's also arguably sort-of static, and single events like the plunging of a comet into Jupiter or a fireball sighting might be excluded because they are more event-like.

#### (Time-) Dispersion

That there was no dispersion tag surprised me since it's such an important concept and tool for measuring distances. But I wonder if it should have been *time-dispersion* to distinguish it from *wavelength-dispersion*. It's the same phenomenon physically, but observationally effect is treated in the time domain in radio astronomy and in the spatial domain for atmospheric dispersion and chromatic aberration.

What do others think?

---

Gratuitous FRB converted to audio: